# Can I get the GPS coordinate in Revit?

Tags: revit-api, revit

Can I get any GPS position in Revit?

Suppose I had set the survey point to {25.039549, 121.560771} and set project base point on the survey point. If I want to know where is the {25.100000, 121.60000} in Revit project coordinate, how can I mapping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Revit project coordinates are always in imperial feet, like all [Revit database length units](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/03/units-and-revitlookup.html#2).

[The Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discusses some aspects of GPS coordinate conversion for [Mobile Device Room Location](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/09/mobile-device-room-location.html).

Answer (score 1):

So it's simpler than I thought. The coordinate relative to project base point is in project coordinates. (no Transform required).

```
XYZ  coord_to_proj_base  =  loc.Point.Subtract( project )
```

Thanks to: FAIR59 of Autodesk [forums](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/finding-coordinates-relative-to-survey-base-point-and-project/td-p/7026871)